# Getting Instance of Thread Local Class in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to refactor some jsps to remove scriplets from them. I have a class that is used quite extensively which uses `ThreadLocal`. My problem is that I can't define it using `jsp:usedBean` because it constructs a new instance when it should do `MyClass.getMyClass()`. This is what is left in my scriplet

```
<%
    ContextDataBean contextData = ContextDataBean.getContextData();
%>
```

Is there a way that I can load this class in my `jsp` without a scriptlet?

Comment: It would be better to show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of the scriptlet in that JSP in order to avoid the usage of `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: You're surely creating this instance in a servlet or filter, right? (otherwise the design is broken anyway). Just set it as a request attribute right there.

Comment: I have added an example, thanks @BalusC it is being set as a request attribute so I can just load that.

Comment: Well, then you've already answered your own question.